Why equation 5.29 in Schroeder's Thermal Physics is not equal to 0?
In Schroeder's "An Introduction to Thermal Physics" in section 5.2 (page 161), Schroeder considers the case of a system that is in thermal contact with a reservoir that is at a constant temperature $T_\text{R}$. I'll quote the relevant section:

The total entropy of the universe can be written as $S_\text{total}=S+S_\text R$, where a subscript $\text R$ indicates a property of the reservoir, while a quantity without a subscript refers to the system alone... let's consider a small change in the total entropy:
$$\text dS_\text{total}=\text dS+\text dS_\text{R}\tag{5.26}\label{5.26}$$
I would like to write this quantity entirely in terms of system variables. To do so, I'll apply the thermodynamic identity, in the form $$\text dS=\frac1T\ \text dU+\frac PT\ \text dV-\frac\mu T\ \text dN\tag{5.27}\label{5.27}$$ to the reservoir. First, I'll assume that $V$ and $N$ for the reservoir are fixed - only energy travels in and out of the system. Then $\text dS_\text R=\text dU_\text R/T$, so equation \eqref{5.26} can be written $$\text dS_\text{total}=\text dS+\frac1T_\text R\text dU_\text R\tag{5.28}\label{5.28}$$ But the temperature of the reservoir is the same as the temperature of the system, while the change $\text dU_\text R$ in the reservoir's energy is minus the change $\text dU$ in the system's energy. Therefore, $$\text dS_\text{total}=\text dS-\frac1T\text dU=-\frac1T(\text dU-T\ \text dS)=-\frac1T\ \text dF\tag{5.29}\label{5.29}$$ Aha! Under these conditions (fixed $T$, $V$, and $N$), an increase in the total entropy of the universe is the same thing as a decrease in the Helmholtz free energy of the system. So we can forget about the reservoir, and just remember that the system will do whatever it can to minimize its Helmholtz free energy.

My question is, if $\text dV$ and $\text dN$ are also $0$ for the system, then shouldn't the thermodynamic identity for the system then be $\text dS=\text dU/T$, leading to $\text dS-\text dU/T$ in equation $\eqref{5.29}$ being equal to $0$?

You need to quote a little bit more than this, so that we can check what the author is trying to get at with this derivation.

@naturallyInconsistent I added more to the end of the quote

Well, minimization of $F$ (and other potentials) and maximization of $S$ are always meant to be with regards to possible constraints.

Does this answer your question? Thermodynamics second law variational statement query

@TobiasFünke The quoted text does specify the constraints; I am not able to determine the point you are making. I am not able to figure out the answer to this from your proposed link, but I am sure I am just missing something "obvious"

Yes, the added quotes makes everything much clearer. What Schroeder is doing here is that, starting with the 2nd Law, i.e. maximising entropy of universe, we see that at fixed T,V,N, this is equivalent to minimising F. What you are considering, is that if you have a reversible process, i.e. $\mathrm dS_{\text{total}}=0$, then obviously $\mathrm dS=\mathrm dU/T$ i.e. $\mathrm dF=0$. However, this is a general result; if you are not in equilibrium nor reversible, then the spontaneous irreversible evolution would minimise $F$ with $\mathrm dS\neq\mathrm dU/T$ if needed.

I mean that at fixed $N,T,V$, $F$ is constant, if it were not for possible constraints (e.g. a wall between two systems which could be removed or so; or two systems allowing heat transfer such that $U=U_1+U_2$...). Maybe I am missing the point, though.

@TobiasFünke The text specifies energy transfer. I guess there are some details left out that is leading to the confusion.

This confusion is caused by the schizophrenia of traditional thermodynamic teaching. On the one hand it says that "heat" is only energy transported in motion like work but it is not work, and tries to conflate reversible thermo-statics with irreversible processes happening in time.
Schroeder is talking about $dS_{tot}=dS+\frac{1}{T_R}dU_R$ and goes on to show that also $dS_{tot}=-\frac{1}{T}dF$ when he is assuming a pure thermal irreversible process because his side condition was that $dN=0;dV=0,$ and then there is only thermal interaction.
Your question as to why that is not zero since the Gibbs equation under no work condition says $dS=\frac{dU}{T}$. That is because while it true that $dS_{tot}=dS+\frac{1}{T_R}dU_R$ but $dU=-dU_R$ with $T<T_R$ for "heat" be absorbed spontaneously by the system. Instead in an irreversible "no-work" process $dS_{tot} > 0 $, "the" 2nd law, showing the internally produced entropy must always be positive.
At the end of the process $T=T_R$ but not when it starts. Now the only thing you can say is that during the process $dU-T_R dS = dU-TdS-(T_R-T)dS=-(T_R-T)dS\le 0$ or $dF \le 0$ as a result of the irreversibility at every stage, so by the end you must still have $dF\le 0.$ Gibbs called the quantity $dA= (T-T_R)dS-(p-p_R)dV+(\mu-\mu_R)dN+... \le 0 $ the availability , nowadays it is more popular to call it exergy, the intensive constants $T_R, p_R, \mu_R..$ represent various work reservoirs, thermal, volume, chemical species, etc.,  with which the system may exchange $S, V, N, ...$ extensive quantities.

I am kind of following what you are saying, but I can't make sense of how it would fix what is in the quoted text. Is there anything in the quote that is incorrect, or there just needs to be a more-detailed explanation? Also, what if when $T>T_R$?

It is not that it is incorrect, just it is obscure. It is obscure because it makes you conflate, for lack of better term, the Gibbs equation that holds for two infinitesimally close equilibrium states with an irreversible process that is not described by such equation. If $T>T_R$ then the entropy flow ("heat" flow) is in the opposite direction and the result is the same because then $dS<0$, the system is rejecting thermal energy and the environment absorbs it, and thus $dA=(T-T_R)dS\le 0$ or $dF\le 0$ still holds.

I also dislike this so-called "proof" because it is really backwards from how it should be taught, I believe. That poetically speaking everything after a while turns to shit is really what the meaning of the 2nd law is. And it being the most intuitive concept of all natural phenomena it should be the at the very start of thermodynamics not something to be derived from less obvious considerations. Instead this is what Schroeder does for a very special no-work only thermal energy transport case. My preference would be to start with the axiom $dA\le 0$ or something similar and then get the rest.


My question is, if $\text dV$ and $\text dN$ are also $0$ for the
system, then shouldn't the thermodynamic identity for the system then
be $\text dS=\text dU/T$, leading to $\text dS-\text dU/T$ in equation
$\eqref{5.29}$ being equal to $0$?

Yes, unless the system undergoes some type of spontaneous process, not involving a change in temperature or volume, which then generates entropy making $dF\lt 0$.
There is a discussion of this in the Wikipedia article on Helmholtz Free Energy. See the section Minimum Free Energy and Maximum Work Principles.
Hope this helps.

So you're saying it should be $0$ as presented?

@BioPhysicist Yes. Since $dU_{R}=\delta Q_{R} $ we have $dS_{R}=- \delta Q_{R}/T_{R}$ and $dS_{sys}=+\delta Q_{R}/T_{R}$ making $dS_{total}=0$.

But then he talks about a change in the total entropy of the universe. So there must be some disconnect between the derivation and the conclusion. I'm confused on which part breaks down.

@BioPhysicist. I think (but I’m not sure) I may have found the disconnect. To me the only possible conclusion is dF must be zero. But not being conversant with Helmholtz free energy I looked at the Wikipedia article in which they also acknowledge it would seem dF would have to be zero but there is no contradiction. It appears it has something to do with expanding the number of particles in the system in the system, which I discounted since dN of the reservoir is zero.

Not being good at chemistry I don’t quite understand why. The relevant section in the article is Minimum Free Energy and Maximum Work Principles

Actually I think it says dF has to be equal to or less than zero. It would be zero for a reversible process, which I assumed in my answer, and less than zero for an irreversible process. It appears that irreversible process would be a spontaneous chemical reaction within the system, which I failed to consider

I revised the end of my answer and the first sentence

I think you are correct.  Schroeder here appears to be motivating the idea of free energy, but it seems silly to me to do that in the very circumscribed special case when there is simultaneously no work done on the system, no work done on the reservoir, AND no temperature difference between the two.  In that case not only would $dU = -dU_R$ and $dF = 0$, but there would be no heat flow either, so $dU = dU_R = 0$.  Since free energy is precisely a measure of how much work might ideally be made available in a process, it's odd to bring it up specifically in a situation where the constraints prevent any work from being done.
